# jgitver - maven plugin: Derive version from Git commit, including Git SHA8 String and SNAPSHOT marker

Tags: git, maven, continuous-integration, jgitver

I'll try to keep this question short and simple:

with the jgitver maven plugin I can easily create versions from Git tags. The ${jgitver.calculated_version} variable that I can use in my .pom file will, by default, behave like this:

1. set Git tag "v1.0.0" 
   version: 1.0.0
2. do Git commit
   version: 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Is it possible to (and if so how can I) include the commit hash in the version number, like so?

1. set Git tag "v1.0.0" 
   version: 1.0.0-162ad57
2. do Git commit
   version: 1.0.1-ff8cb8a-SNAPSHOT

The important part is that version numbers from simple (not tagged) commits also end with "SNAPSHOT".

Comment: did the provided answer resolved your question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

in the `.mvn/jgitver.config.xml` file set the property `useGitCommitId` to *true*.
You can also define the expected length of the SHA1 using `gitCommitIdLength`

something like:

```
<useGitCommitId>true</useGitCommitId>
<gitCommitIdLength>8</gitCommitIdLength>  <!-- between [8,40] -->
```

Comment: Hi, I tried using jgitver-maven-plugin [1.2.1] and [1.3.0]. 
This unfortunately only works with "<mavenLike>false</mavenLike>", if i use "<mavenLike>true</mavenLike>" then -SNAPSHOT is appended, but no commitID

Comment: there is IMHO no interest in having the SHA1 together with SNAPSHOT; open an issue on jgitver if you want to discuss further your needs. thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/jgitver/jgitver/issues/135